# PHP error after new install of xampp

Tags: php

I was recently switched computers at work, and am trying to get all my projects up and running again.  I am working on testing some php/html/javascript pages for a website using a local xampp server.  I had everything working properly on the only computer, but when I try to load the pages now I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

I have tried a php-only test page, so I know the sever is capable of parsing php.

I also know it is not the short tag issue, as all of the php code is wrapped in

```
<?php...?>
```

Are there any other configuration settings that would be causing this issue?

Comment: We can't help you without some information ;) is there an error in your logs? Or can you print the line? Are you really sure that your short Tags are enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message doesn't look like a PHP error. Check [this discussion](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/Uj6DitMGK1A) maybe you can find the solution there.

It seems the error is reported by Google Chrome when it expects to parse a `.js` file and it finds HTML (or PHP?) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a JavaScript error, you should check your js code, not php.

The following reasons might cause this error:

1. href attribute value "javascript: void ()", no brackets add "0"

   ```
   <a href="javascript:void()">Button</a>  // error
   <a href="javascript:void(0)">Button</a> // correct
   ```
2. Non-compliant JSON string
3. etc.